# Using custom markers in fusion-tables with address already geocoded locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I was trying to follow this example http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples/source/browse/trunk/fusiontables/custom_markers.html?spec=svn2515&r=2515, to create custom markers.
I tried to change the example to use my data.  The difference is that my data is already geocoded.  I had trouble trying to figure why it didnt work when I changed the table id and the columns on the code.
So i printed the 'Address' on the original code and the one with my data.

The original code with the sample fusion-table, outputs the location like this

```
(37.4471132, -122.1602044)
```

Because my table is already geocoded I took away most of the function

```
function codeAddress(row) {
    alert(row[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                map : map,
                position : row[1],
                //this is where the magic happens!
                icon : new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/fusion_tables-32.png")
            }); 
}
```

But the alert only diplays the coordinate a little bit different

```
<Point><coordinates>-78.423652,-0.203057,0.0</coordinates></Point>
```

So yeah, that is what I think it is not working

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that `position :` has to be followed by a `google.maps.LatLng`.

It looks like the `row` data is from KML, you need to extract the first two numbers to create the LatLng.

Comment: And don't forget that KML is Longitude followed by Latitude.

Comment: Hello, i found the answer several hours later, but I dont have enough points answer my own questions, you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mia DiLorenzo is right, the [MarkerOption `position`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) expects a [LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).

[Look at this example](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/custom_markers.html), which is very similar to yours, but it uses the `Coordinates` field to create the marker.

The example assumes, that the data in the Coordinates field is comma-separated "lat,lng"
e.g. `47.7672,-3.2022`

But if your data happens to be in KML format then you can just extract the lat/lng values. The values are in order: longitude, latitude, and altitude (see the [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates) for details about KML `coordinates`):

```
function createLatLngObject(kmlString) {
   //remove XML tags from input
   var xmlRegEx = /<\/?\w+>/;
   var kmlValue = kmlString.replace(xmlRegEx,'');

   // now kmlValue contains e.g. -78.423652,-0.203057,0.0

   //extract latitude and longitude
   var coordinates = kmlValue.split(",");
   var lat = coordinates[1];
   var lng = coordinates[0];

   return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
}

function createMarker(row) {
   var latlng = createLatLngObject(row[1]);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map, 
       position: latlng,
       icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/fusion_tables-32.png")
    });
}
```